# Log Request time in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, mvc-mini-profiler

I am running on a performance issue with ASP.Net 2.0 Application.

A page takes atmost 20+ secs to load in a browser.

I would like to know where the problem is occurring, i.e in browser(rendering) or in server(processing).

**Is there a way to log the time taken for each request in IIS 7.5?**

Do we need any code in global.asax or filter that do this stuff? I read about integrating MiniProfiler from http://miniprofiler.com/

Not sure will this work for ASP.Net 2.0 web application.

Any suggestion or help?

Comment: without knowing your code writting style cant say anything

Comment: To profile you should be able to use the built in profiler. Not sure about profiling the client.

Comment: @Freelancer, I have not writtent any code yet

Comment: http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/121_Display_Request_Processing_Time_in_ASPNet_pages.aspx seems helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to profile your code.
I suggest you the following ways:

1. **CLR Profiler** (Application by microsoft to see the time spent by each function, allocution memory etc ...) for asp and .Net applications

   [How use clr profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx)

   [Download Clr profiler from microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/2/442d67c7-a1c1-4884-9715-803a7b485b82/clr%20profiler.exe)
2. **Internet Explorer debug mode**

   Simply with the debug window. By pressing "F12" for "Internet Explorer" and then in the onge "Network", click on "start capture". You can see the call to the function / script with time for each call. With exceptions.