# Logging request processing time in IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8, iis-logs

I've an ASP.NET 4.0 application deployed on IIS 8.0. I want to to log all requests that take time longer than a configured time. Is it possible to do that in IIS 8.0?

PS: I found a similar question here [Log Request time in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142294/log-request-time-in-iis), but it is for IIS 7.5.

Comment: What about [IIS logs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313437) enabled with the field `time-taken`?